# method fillArrayList to fill two arraylist lists

Tags: java, arraylist

how can I fill the two lists with corresponding elements in method fillArrayList the user must enter the values

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Assignment1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      System.out.println("Enter your lists = ");
      fillArrayList(list1,list2);

    }

    public static void fillArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> L1 ,ArrayList<Integer> L2 )
    {
           //don't know what to do here to fill two lists from the user , really need help

    }
```

Comment: Why did you add the `javascript` tag?

Comment: You haven't done anything till yet? Try it out first, if you fail, then we are happy to help you.

Comment: deja vu - didnt I see this yesterday?

Comment: @Azodious with Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (system.in);

Comment: @rain. We can't see that code. Common let some code rain on your post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I Declare two ArrayList lists list1 & list2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057646/how-can-i-declare-two-arraylist-lists-list1-list2)

Comment: @RohitJain if the user must fill two lists , should we do two fillarraylist method ? or we can do it in one method ?

Comment: @rain. I would say just, one `fillArrayList` method is enough, and call it two times for two lists. So, your method should only fill 1 arraylist at a time.

Comment: Aww! You just asked this question 11 hours back: - [how-can-i-declare-two-arraylist-lists-list1-list2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057646/how-can-i-declare-two-arraylist-lists-list1-list2). How come you posted it again? Without any improvement?  You should try writing your code first, and then only post your problems here, else you won't learn anything.

Comment: @RohitJain I try alot and i read all my doctor slides, but I didn't put my tries here .. also I have to submit my assignment very soon .. sorry :(

Comment: @rain. Its ok for now, but from now on, you should do, or at least try your assignments yourself. And don't postpone it till the dead-end, so that you don't have to panic.

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry for the inconvenience,finally I finish my assignment , but there's something wrong with it in output can u help me ?

Comment: @rain. Unfortunately, you don't have enough reputation, else we would have chatted in chat room. Still tell me what's the problem>?

Comment: @RohitJain
3. Call the method merge to merge the two lists in list1 so that the list1 remains sorted.

`public static void merge (ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2)
    {
     int i;
     int n=list1.size();
     int pos , j=0;
     
     for (pos =0 ;pos<n ; pos++)
     
     {
     }
     for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
     if (list1.get(j)>list2.get(pos))
     
     list1.add(pos,list2.get(pos));
     else 
     j++;
    } 
    }`
I think the problem here

Comment: @rain. Ok, now I think you can add this as a new question.

Comment: @RohitJain hmmm , ppl here will be upset if I do :) 
 thank you any way.

Comment: @rain. Nono. No one here gets upset, if you ask legitimate question. if you have shown some effort, we are happy to help you here. You should know how to ask a good question.  See [Faq on How to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: @RohitJain okay I add it in new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should modify your `fillArrayList` signature to just fill one list at a time. And you can invoke it twice for your two arraylist.

So, your method should be like: -

```
public static void fillArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> myList) {
    /* Let the code be same as the one in @AmitD's post */

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter elemetns for List: Enter -1 to end ");

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int i = scanner.nextInt();
            if (i == -1)
                break;

            myList.add(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid value Please enter integer");
            scanner.next();
        }
    }

}
```

Then declare your two lists as instance variable, outside the main method. And use `List` for reference type.

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Now, from the main method, you can invoke this method twice for each list like this: -

```
fillArrayList(list1);
fillArrayList(list2);
```

And back in your main method, you can print your list, as the change you do in `fillArrayList` method will get reflected there also.

```
System.out.println(list1);
System.out.println(list2);
```

Comment: okay now I knew how to fill two arraylist lists in one method , thank you thank you thank you , u save my life :D

Comment: @rain. You're welcome. And remember, you don't fill two arraylist in one method. You just fill one arraylist. And you invoke that method twice.

Comment: Using -1 to end it is a bad idea, as they may want to put -1 in their list. You might be able to check if they finished inputting/ended the line/entered a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your fillArrayList, you require a loop. Since an arraylist has an undetermined size, you will be needing some sort of termination input. If the numbers required are all positive, an easy termination input would be a negative number. In other words, use a while loop and if the input is negative, stop looping.

In order to get values from the user, use the Scanner class. The method required to get an integer is the nextInt() method.

Once you got integer, simply add it to the lists, using the method the add method.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to take input from user, read it as `int` or `Integer` and just call [ArrayList.add(E o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to get input from user and add it to list.

```
public static void fillArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> l1,
        ArrayList<Integer> l2) {
    // don't know what to do here to fill two lists from the user , really
    // need help
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter elemetns for List 1: Enter -1 to end ");

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int i = scanner.nextInt();
            if (i == -1)
                break;
            l1.add(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid value Please enter integer");
            scanner.next();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Your List :"+ l1);

    //Do same for List 2
}
```